# What is wrong with my PHP session variables?

Tags: php, session

I cannot get $userLabel ($_SESSION['nickname']) to print. I am using phpmyadmin with apache on a localhost.

I cannot seem to figure out to problem. I have the row made in phpmyadmin and I know it is in row 4. Could it be a wrong method or something? I am new to PHP and trying to best to figure it out. Any solutions or addition help would be great! Thank you!

login:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    include_once("connection.php");
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, nickname FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND activated = '1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if ($query) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $userId = $row[0];
        $dbUsername = $row[1];
        $dbPassword = $row[2];
        $userLabel = $row[4];
    }

    if ($username == $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
        $_SESSION['nickname'] = $userLabel;


        header('Location: user.php');
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error: password mismatch.";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">
        </li>
    </form>
</body>
<html>
```

webpage:

```
if  (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $userLabel = $_SESSION['nickname'];
} 
else {
    header('Locaion: index.php');
    die();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p><font color="white">Hello <?php echo $userLabel; ?>.</font></
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Did you started session first? session_start() on the top of the page?

Comment: Yes I did. And if I change the code in html document to <?php echo $username; ?> it prints just fine.

Comment: First check the if condition, weather it goes inside it to set session ? I mean debug the code line by line.

Comment: in your code you have used $userLabel = $row[4];, and your query is "SELECT id, username, password, nickname FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND activated = '1' LIMIT 1", try changing it to $userLabel = $row[3];

Comment: this is because there is another row in my database called active. Active is row 3. I have tried this anyways, no fix.

Comment: try a var dump of the result, since you are selecting id, username, password, nickname the index for nickname will be 3

Comment: How does one do a var dump? Sorry I'm new to php.

Comment: echo '<pre>',print_r($row),'</pre>';

Comment: How exactly will this help me

Comment: i'm sure if you change the index to $userLabel = $row[3]; and take out the color white in font from the html it will show up
<p><font>Hello <?php echo $userLabel; ?>.</font></p>

Comment: No sir. Just did that and the output is the same.. "Hello ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $userLabel = $row[3]; ?>

<p><font>Hello <?php echo $userLabel; ?>.</font></p>
```

Comment: Same result. I already had session_start();} but adding the previous code did not change anything.

Comment: No sir. Just did that and the output is the same.. "Hello ."

Comment: This answer seems to be correct: If the select is exactly as posted then `$row[3]` is the correct nickname. Also, `session_start()` should be called on top of *each* php file that uses `$_SESSION`... else I cannot see anything wrong...

Comment: What kind of wizardry is this?! Thank you so much. My only question is why row 3? In phpMyAdmin its in row 5. Making it $row[4]; right? Because you count from 0

Comment: since your select statement is id, username, password, nickname it indexes the output as 0-id,1-username,2-password,3-nickname regardless of the columns in the table